# Symfony2: how can I make a <button type="submit"> or just <button>

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

My buttons from the Symfony form component come out as:

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Of course, this doesn't submit the form.

What I'd like is:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
// or
<button>Submit</button>
```

I'd rather not use an `<input type="submit">` so I have more control over the look of the button. I'd also like to use the form component instead of straight up HTML at this point (although that's a valid option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the button with the Form Type of `submit` like this:

```
$builder->add('button', 'submit');
```

The documentation for the [Symfony Form Type Submit is here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html).

Comment: This only adds a class of save to the button. It does not change the type :(

Comment: how about this ? 
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)->add('save', 'submit')->getForm();

Comment: What's the button HTML that you end up with?

Comment: Figured it out. Not quite as you had, but I've updated your answer to make it correct. Pointed me in the right direction though. Thanks!